# How can "squeeze-repeated" words?

Tags: linux, bash, tr

How can "squeeze-repeated" words?
similar to "squeeze repeated characters" with `tr -s ''`

I would like to change for example:

```
hello.hello.hello.hello
```

to

```
hello
```

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: How do you justify `hellohellohellohello` ==> `hello`?  So `hello` should be `helo`?

Comment: First, you'll have to define what a word is.  By most normal definitions, `hellohellohellohello` is a single word (that humans recognize as containing the same sub-word, `hello`, four times).  If you've got to look for arbitrarily long repeats within a single contiguous block of non-space characters, you've got quite a problem on your hands — I'm not aware of any standard tools that will address the job.  What will be the output for the input `banana hello hello abracadabra`?  Is it `bana helo abracad`? If not, what, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a way:

```
$ cat a
hello hello bye but bye yeah
hello yeah
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=" "} 
  {  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
       if (!($i in a)) {printf "%s%s",$i,OFS; a[$i]=$i}
     }; 
    delete a;
    print ""
  }' a
hello bye but yeah 
hello yeah
```

You can change the field separator:

```
$ cat a
hello|hello|bye|but|bye|yeah
hello|yeah
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if (!($i in a)) {printf "%s%s",$i,OFS; a[$i]=$i}}; delete a; print ""}' a
hello|bye|but|yeah|
hello|yeah|
```

Comment: Did you see the sample input?  `hellohellohellohello`!

Comment: Oh haha then the answer must be `echo "hello"`.

Comment: Very true.  I too sought a [clarification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118225/how-can-squeeze-repeated-words#comment28269864_19118225) but, alas, no response.